# Uploading large files as stream to S3 in .NET without buffering

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Our application generates large (20GB+) ZIP archives on demand to a stream.   We would like to upload the stream as it is produced to an S3 bucket **without ever buffering the complete file**.  We do not know the size of the data beforehand.

We have been trying to make this work with [TranserUtility](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet1/latest/apidocs/html/T_Amazon_S3_Transfer_TransferUtility.htm) but cannot seem to get the upload to happen without buffering.  The problem seems to be that we need something to produce content on the stream simultaneously while the S3 upload is consuming it.  We've tried several scenarios with TPL that did not pan out.

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html) seems to explain how to do file-based operations and does not discuss working with streams.

Anyone know of a simple solution for our use case?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it seems the multipart upload API is the way to go, as you receive a chunk upload that part to s3 as well. Here is an example walkthrough of what to do.

Here’s what your application needs to do:

1. Separate the source object into multiple parts. This might be a logical separation where you simply decide how many parts to use and how big they’ll be, or an actual physical separation accomplished using the Linux split command or similar (e.g. the hk-split command for Windows).
2. Initiate the multipart upload and receive an upload id in return. This request to S3 must include all of the request headers that would usually accompany an S3 PUT operation (Content-Type, Cache-Control, and so forth).
3. Upload each part (a contiguous portion of an object’s data) accompanied by the upload id and a part number (1-10,000 inclusive). The part numbers need not be contiguous but the order of the parts determines the position of the part within the object. S3 will return an ETag in response to each upload.
4. Finalize the upload by providing the upload id and the part number / ETag pairs for each part of the object.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-multipart-upload/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/mpuoverview.html

Edit:

Another option is to use creating a Kinesis stream to capture all the data and then store it in s3. There is a pre built (java) library, the Amazon Kinesis Connector Library.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-connectors

.Net Client Lib https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-client-net

https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/details/

Comment: The API we're integrating with produces its output to a stream that must be passed in.  We're attempting to create a write-only custom stream implementation that will buffer one chunk at a time and then upload as a part.  Shocked that this doesn't exist.  Azure Blob Storage supports it out of the box.

Comment: @kenchilada I added info around using Kinesis Streams and saving it to s3.